# Unique factorization of representations in rigid tensor categories

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, monoidal-categories

Consider the category $\mathrm{Rep}_{\mathbb{C}}(GL_n)$ of representations of GL_n over complex numbers. Then a theorem of Rajan(See https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2004.160.683) says that if $V_1, V_2, \dots, V_n$ and $W_1, W_2, \dots, W_m$ are irreducible representations of GL_n of nonzero highest weights such that $V_1 \otimes \dots \otimes V_n \cong W_1 \otimes \dots \otimes W_m$, then $m=n$ and $V_i \simeq W_{\sigma(i)} \otimes \det^{\alpha_i}$, where $\alpha_i$ are integers and $\sigma$ is a permutation of $n$.

Recall that Deligne had constructed the semisimple rigid abelian tensor categories(See https://publications.ias.edu/deligne/paper/438). Can we say something similar in the context of $\mathrm{Rep}(GL_t)$ where $t \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{N}$? More precisely I have the following question

$\it{Question}$ : Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ and $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_m$ be irreducible objects of the category $\mathrm{Rep}(GL_t)$(for $t \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$) over some algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Suppose $X_1 \otimes \dots \otimes X_n \cong Y_1 \otimes \dots \otimes Y_m$. Is $m=n$? Are there any relation between individual objects $X_i$ and $Y_j$ as in the above mentioned result?

More generally, tet $(\mathcal{C}, \otimes)$ be a rigid abelian category. You may even assume semisimple. I wonder if we impose the condition of "unique factorization" as above then would it be possible to say that there cannot be too many such categories. Perhaps something in terms of growth of lengths of tensor power of objects?

I have found following related query but with no answers : [Has the notion of a unique factorization category been defined and studied?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/202970/172843).

Apologies if the question is too naive. Any comments, references and suggestions are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: What is $\mathrm{GL}_t$ for $t\not\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: @VladimirSotirov There does not exists such a group, but there are categories $\mathrm{Rep}(GL_t)$ constructed by Deligne which is loosely speaking constructed by interpolation of categories $\mathrm{Rep}(GL_n)$. Please see the article https://publications.ias.edu/deligne/paper/438.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a condition missing in your statement of Rajan's theorem in the first paragraph? The way it is written now I feel I can use it to prove that $1 = 2$

Comment: @Vincent $V_i$ and $W_j$ are irreducible. Does that help? Maybe you can let me know as to what condition I am missing and I will edit the question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I looked it up in the link to the article. The missing condition is that $V_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes V_n \cong W_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes W_m$. In retrospect I could have guessed that that must have been it from the rest of your post. But either way it was clear that *some* relationship between the $V_i$ and $W_j$ should have been given in order to force $m = n$.

Comment: It is a very interesting result btw! I didn't know this

Comment: @Vincent Thank you for pointing this out. I will make this edit. I forgot this very important condition. I agree that the result is quite interesting. It seems that such conditions should force some strong constraint on any tensor category. Wondered is this has been explored and hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, this follows from the case for $GL_n$ basically for free.  Tensor product multiplicities in $Rep(GL_t)$ are the same as for $GL_n$ for all $n \gg 0$. So any counterexample to the above theorem for $t \in \mathbb{C} - \mathbb{N}$ would produce a counterexample for $GL_n$ for all large $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a nice argument. Would you also like to comment on the vague question in the next paragraph to the Question?

Comment: For the vague question:  This property can fail for finite groups -- for example it fails for $A_5$, there we have  $V_4 \otimes V_5 \otimes V_3 \cong V_4 \otimes V_5 \otimes V'_3$  where the subscript denotes the dimension (there are two non-isomorphic representations of dimension 3).  Characterizing exactly when it holds is probably hard.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. This is very helpful. I will think a little more and maybe in future will have a better question. Thanks again for your  nice answer and helpful comments.